# Create multiple UUIDs for postgres jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a database of a couple million records that look like this:

```json
{
  "id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20",
  "circulationNotes": [
    {
      "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
      "noteType": "Check in"
    },
    {
      "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
      "noteType": "Check out"
    }
  ],
  "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917",
  "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"
}
```

I need to generate and add a uuid to each of the circulationNotes lacking them (~ 10K records) so the desired output is

```json
{
  "id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20",
  "circulationNotes": [
    {
      "id": "3794824a-b814-4b94-b7c4-d8be53088a51",
      "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
      "noteType": "Check in"
    },
    {
      "id": "175989f9-16f4-4cfe-a1aa-d665ec1263e7",
      "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
      "noteType": "Check out"
    }
  ],
  "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917",
  "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"
}
```

I can select the records I want to update with the query:

```
SELECT id 
  FROM mod_inventory_storage.item
 WHERE EXISTS 
       ( SELECT * 
           FROM jsonb_array_elements(jsonb->'circulationNotes')           
          WHERE value->'note' IS NOT NULL
            AND value->'id' IS NULL )
```

(data is such that if one note has the problem, both do)

but how do I update the jsonb object with uuids in each entry within circulationNotes?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your case with the following

```
create table test (id serial, text jsonb);

insert into test (text) values ('{
    "id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20",
    "circulationNotes": [
        {
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check in"
        },
        {
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check out"
        }
    ],
    "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917",
    "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"
}');
insert into test (text) values ('{
    "id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20",
    "circulationNotes": [
        {
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check in"
        },
        {
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check out"
        }
    ],
    "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917",
    "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"
}');
insert into test (text) values ('{
    "id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20",
    "circulationNotes": [
        {
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check in"
        },
        {
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check out"
        }
    ],
    "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917",
    "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"
}');
insert into test (text) values ('{
    "id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20",
    "circulationNotes": [
        {
            "id": "3794824a-b814-4b94-b7c4-d8be53088a51",     
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check in"
        },
        {
            "id": "175989f9-16f4-4cfe-a1aa-d665ec1263e7",
            "note": "REFERENCE BOOK",
            "noteType": "Check out"
        }
    ],
    "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917",
    "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"
}');
```

Then, to solve the issue I split the problem in 2 steps: decomposing and recomposing.
**Step 1**: create a table at `circulationNotes` and place the new `id` column with the following

```
with fixing_id as (
    select id, 
        text->'id' json_id, 
        text->'holdingsRecordId' holdingsRecordId, 
        text->'permanentLocationId' as permanentLocationId, 
        ('{"id":"'||uuid_generate_v1()||'"}')::jsonb || jsonb_array_elements((text->'circulationNotes')::jsonb)  as circulationNotes 
    from test
    where exists 
         (select * 
         FROM jsonb_array_elements(text->'circulationNotes')             
         where value->'note' is not null
         and value->'id' is null))
select * from fixing_id
```

The result is the following

```
 id |                json_id                 |            holdingsrecordid            |          permanentlocationid           |                                         circulationnotes
----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20" | "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917" | "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39" | {"id": "4ad151ea-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check in"}
  1 | "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20" | "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917" | "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39" | {"id": "4ad155fa-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check out"}
  2 | "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20" | "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917" | "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39" | {"id": "4ad15708-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check in"}
  2 | "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20" | "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917" | "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39" | {"id": "4ad157a8-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check out"}
  3 | "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20" | "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917" | "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39" | {"id": "4ad15870-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check in"}
  3 | "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20" | "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917" | "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39" | {"id": "4ad15906-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check out"}
(6 rows)
```

Check that I'm using the `uuid_generate_v1()` function to generate the uuid (you'll need the `uuid-ossp` extension`). And that the` jsonb_array_elements`creates a row for each`text->'circulationNotes'` item.

**Step 2**: Aggregate from the `fixing_id` with `jsonb_agg` and rebuild the json object with `jsonb_build_object`

```
select id,
    jsonb_build_object('id',json_id,'circulationNotes',jsonb_agg(circulationNotes) ,'holdingsRecordId',holdingsRecordId,'permanentLocationId',permanentLocationId)
from fixing_id
group by id,
    json_id, 
    holdingsRecordId,
    permanentLocationId
```

result

```
 id |                                                                                                                                                                                          jsonb_build_object
----+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 | {"id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20", "circulationNotes": [{"id": "b71fc232-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check in"}, {"id": "b71fc39a-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check out"}], "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917", "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"}
  3 | {"id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20", "circulationNotes": [{"id": "b71fc624-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check in"}, {"id": "b71fc6c4-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check out"}], "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917", "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"}
  2 | {"id": "aa1e24cd-2825-490f-8ccb-60bd4914dc20", "circulationNotes": [{"id": "b71fc4b2-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check in"}, {"id": "b71fc55c-f5c9-11eb-a458-42010af00961", "note": "REFERENCE BOOK", "noteType": "Check out"}], "holdingsRecordId": "fd79910f-4d11-41b4-9e53-198fff089917", "permanentLocationId": "cee4d952-da5a-4d34-bb0a-a5d4d4581f39"}
(3 rows)
```

The whole query is

```
with fixing_id as (
    select id, 
        text->'id' json_id, 
        text->'holdingsRecordId' holdingsRecordId, 
        text->'permanentLocationId' as permanentLocationId, 
        ('{"id":"'||uuid_generate_v1()||'"}')::jsonb || jsonb_array_elements((text->'circulationNotes')::jsonb)  as circulationNotes 
    from test
    where exists 
         (select * 
         FROM jsonb_array_elements(text->'circulationNotes')             
         where value->'note' is not null
         and value->'id' is null))
select id,
    jsonb_build_object('id',json_id,'circulationNotes',jsonb_agg(circulationNotes) ,'holdingsRecordId',holdingsRecordId,'permanentLocationId',permanentLocationId)
from fixing_id
group by id,
    json_id, 
    holdingsRecordId,
    permanentLocationId
```

Comment: I really appreciate the thought you put into this. My actual records contain a lot more fields than I posted, so I'm hoping to avoid rebuilding the objects. I've been playing with something to the effect of select jsonb_insert(jsonb, '{circulationNotes,0}', '{"id": " || uuid_generate_v4() || "}'::jsonb) from mod_inventory_storage.item
where exists 
(select * 
FROM jsonb_array_elements(jsonb->'circulationNotes')     
where value->'note' is not null
and value->'id' is null) which achieves what I need, but I'm unable to figure out the syntax to pass uuid

Comment: Obviously with the solution I'm playing with, I have to run the query twice for each note (positions 0 and 1), but that is acceptable. But I can only pass strings and not separate unique identifiers to the id